# The return false onclick anchor not completely working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lightbox overlay and I'm using the below to cancel out the browser window scroll for the href anchor of "#".  I have it working so it doesn't scroll the window on the initial click however upon closing the lightbox overlay the browser scrolls to the top and # is appended to the URL.

```
<a href="#" onclick="somefunction(); return false;">...
```

or even this...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="somefunction(); return false;">...
```

The link is on a clickable image which the onclick function fires the overlay to pop up.

Andy ideas how to prevent the browser from scrolling to top upon exiting the overlay?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd suggest not using an anchor tag at all. If you don't want an HREF value, then it's really not a link to another page, so probably not truly a link. If the site has to be accessible sans javascript, then you need to think about this some more and come up with a solution that will allow for a true href value that will link to the actual content.

However, if you're OK with this being a JS-required app, then you can do this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="somefunction(); return false;">
```

But, again, this is really something you are clicking on to update the UI rather than go somewhere, so I'd just make it a DIV, give it an onclick event, and be done with it. But be sure to give the div a tabindex so that it can be keyboard-accessible.

Comment: onclick="blah(); return false;" does not stop the default anchor tag if there is an error in blah().  Adding href="javascript:;" did the trick.  Saved my butt.  Thanks DA.

Comment: `not using an anchor tag` - I disagree. What about browsers that don't support javascript (like Opera mini)? "Javascripted" anchor is a good cross-browser solution. If the browser does not support javascript, its task can be done server-side thanks to anchor href.

Comment: @matewka I addressed all of that in the answer. If you need to support non-JS options, then there has to be an actual href that links to an actual page.

Answer (score 5):

You should avoid the `#` href and the `javascript:` pseudo protocol.

A link should always point to a valid resource.

If you can't use a more suitable element like `button` (as your example suggest), I would use `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the default behaviour.

Comment: Using anchor tags to execute javascript is a web standard. There's nothing wrong with it. Even google agrees.

Comment: @Amalgovinus Why would you abuse an `a` element when the `button` element exists. What about *opening links in new windows*, *copying link location*, *mail this link* and all the other stuff the browser supplies but makes it unusable if you decide to make them `a` elements for some reason.

Comment: If I were assigning an onclick to a bunch of text, I'd much rather use an anchor tag so that I don't have to reformat the button's styles. Plus, messing with form elements in the past--especially on mobile devices--has been a pain due to the varying ways OSes will render them. At least for the case of clickable text with a javascript action, a button is overkill. There's nothing illegitimate about anchor javascript.

Comment: @Amalgovinus It takes 10 seconds to create a class that removes the browser's default styles for the `button` element. How is a `button` also overkill? It's an element, with no more *weight* than an `a` element. Why do you also think that [Bootstrap provides a *btn-link* class?](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)