# Can I shorten this script? (update DB table and refresh)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I really want to know if there is a shorter alternative to writing this code. I have attempted to shorten it to 2 or 1 functions and achieved miserable failure. I'm seeking constructive feedback!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function f_solar_1() {
    $.get("f_solar_1.php");
    return false;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh(){
location.reload(true);}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function both(){
    f_solar_1()
    setTimeout(refresh, 5);
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="both();">Activate</a>
```

Details:

This code is an excerpt from my php page that displays a table from my mysql database (I'm using wamp).

The "Activate" text at the bottom is supposed to UPDATE a variable on that table, and does so via the f_solar_1.php file.

The issue is the table reflecting the database does not automatically reflect this change.

So I made a "reload()" function to refresh the page, and the "both()" function to time the refresh after updating the database.

I have known basic html for a while, but I am new to mysql, ajax, and php as of this morning, and this is my attempt to dive into it.

My code works fine, it just bothers me not knowing if I can accomplish the same thing within one function.

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: Thankyou to Dat Pham for pointing me in the right direction!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newfunc(){
$.get( "f_solar_1.php", function( data ) {
location.reload(true);
});}
</script>

<span onclick="newfunc();">newfunc</span>
```

The code is all in one function (well...) and without causing a refresh and php recall timing conflict.

Comment: where is your php code

Comment: the external php file is a straight forward $sql script of updating a variable on my mysql table and everything that surrounds that such as statement preparation and execution as well as a catch. I was under the impression that that code could not be improved on so I did not include it because it is server side only. The script I questioned efficiency on was the one I posted originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making 1 function do all the thing is considered bad practice, a function should do and only do an atomic task. Your code is fine except some minor points:

- ajax call $.get() and location.reload should not be used with each other as this destroy the meaning of ajax call. You can pass a callback function to handle data from backend server like
  `$.get( "f_solar_1.php", function( data ) {
      alert( "Load was performed." );
  });`
- Combine all your script tags into 1 with all your function declare

Regards,

Comment: Despite your advice against mixing ajax and location.reload... the result is Beautiful!!!

I have a feeling (now I'm new at this, so no credability here), that instantly refreshing the page inturrupts calling in the php page that updates the mysql database table, which is why I could not include everything as one function. Your suggestion solved this. I knew there was a more efficient way!

My next step is to research the potentials of callback functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the database through the backend (phpmyadmin for example) and verified if the changes are being made even though it's not displaying?

i'm wondering if your page isn't really refreshing, and simply going to "#".  Check the "return false" - it's not really applying to the "A" link, you would have to put "return false" in the 'both' function for that to cancel the link.  But you might not want to do it that way after taking a minute to read this: [The return false onclick anchor not completely working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644665/the-return-false-onclick-anchor-not-completely-working)

additionally, I'd recommend using the jquery add event listener to trigger your function calls, and get the onClick out of your html tag.  Bonus if you learn how to do it without jquery.  Read this real quick [jquery href and onclick separation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852482/jquery-href-and-onclick-separation)

Comment: My page works as I intended, the behavior of the page doesn't need to be fixed. It is the code itself just feels inefficient having 3 functions plus a separate php file just to instantly update the table displayed on the page at the click of a button. I just thought of all the on/off switches next to each variable I'd have to create, and multiplying that by 3 functions each. I am aware I could do this same thing using a text field to simplify, but I want to know if this method is feasible.

Comment: I've thoroughly explored both articles you have provided and mirrored every suggested script and can get each code to function and perform the actions I want, until I substitute their function with the refresh script. This leads me to believe that the browser is triggering the refresh congruently with the php file that updates the mysql database table and not giving it time to execute. If this is the case, my delayed reload function is neccessary just as I have it unless there is a cleaner method of achieving the same effect

Comment: that I am unaware of, in which case I was hoping to learn (today is my day 2 of programming aside from html in notepad).
If you are imagining a method that is jquery free please share. I'll figure out the scripting part if you just name the language alternitive and tell me it is possible.
Thank you for your feedback.